# Error Message Help in Java

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am working on a program that is supposed to read in a file of employee hours, store that file in a 2D array, print that 2D array, then print the total hours for each employee. That's kind of vague, I know, but my problem is more with this one error message I keep getting, than it is with the program itself. Here is the code I have

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int employeeNum;
        int i;
        int j;
        int empId;
        int days;
        int[][] hoursArray = new int[employeeNum][7];
        int[] totalHours = new int[hoursArray.length];
        int[] indexList = new int[totalHours.length];

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("../instr/prog2.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);
             employeeNum = fin.nextInt();
                for(empId = 0; empId < employeeNum;
                empId++)
                    for(days = 0; days < 7; days++)
                        hoursArray[empId][days] = fin.nextInt();
        System.out.println(hoursArray[empId][days]);

        for(i = 0; i < hoursArray.length; i++)          for(j = 0; j < hoursArray[i].length; j++)
                totalHours[i] += hoursArray[i][j];

        sortIndex(totalHours.length, indexList);

        for (int index = totalHours.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
                System.out.println("Employee " + indexList[index] + ": "
            + totalHours[index]);
    }

    static void sortIndex(int[] list, int[] indexList) {
        int max;
        int maxIndex;
        int i;
        int j; 
        for(i = 0; i < indexList.length; i++)
            indexList[i] = i;

        for(i = list.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            max = list[i];
            maxIndex = i;

          for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    if(max < list[j]) {
                    max = list[j];
                    maxIndex = j;
                }
            }

        if(maxIndex != i) {
            list[maxIndex] = list[i];
            list[i] = max;

            int temp = indexList[i];
            indexList[i] = indexList[maxIndex];
            indexList[maxIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
 }
```

I keep getting the error message :

`"The method sortIndex(int[], int[]) in the type Prog2 is not applicable for the arguments (int, int[])"`

at this portion of code :

```
sortIndex(totalHours.length, indexList);
```

I've never come across this error before and have no idea how to fix it. This particular assignment was a variation of one in the book which has a program written for it, but the problem in the book doesn't deal with files. Our professor said this should be simple since we can basically type out the exact program in the book only writing code to read in the input from a file. So this portion of the code that I am having the problem with is straight from the book, so I have no idea what I'm supposed to do to fix it. Please help.

Comment: `totalHours.length` is `int` and not `int[]`

Comment: in error message the method is `sortAndKeepIndex(int[], int[])` and in code it is `sortIndex(totalHours.length, indexList)` ?????

Comment: There is no method in this code relating to `sortAndKeepIndex`

Comment: I think you need to call `sortIndex(totalHours, indexList);`

Comment: My bad, I've tried so many different things only to get the same result, must've forgotten to go back and correct this. I'll edit it now.

Comment: I don't understand how totalHours isn't an int[] when I declared it as int[] totalHours = new int[hoursArray.length];??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory:

The method `void sortIndex(int[] list, int[] indexList)` need two 1D array as input but while calling it you are sending the first argument as totalHours.length which is the length of the array and a int value and not a int 1D array.

```
sortIndex(totalHours.length, indexList);
```

It seems like you need to call :

```
   sortIndex(totalHours, indexList);
```

as totalHours is a 1D array.

Comment: Ohhh ok, I see what's going on now. Thank you!